# Convert latitude-longtitude to x-y for the Amersfoort RD New (epsg:28992)

Tags: .net, gps, coordinates, gis, coordinate-transformation

Who can help me convert GPS latitude-longtitude to x-y coordinates for the Amersfoort RD New (epsg:28992) projected system.

My startpoint (data from the GPS device) is something like this:
"$GPGGA,071132.784, 5157.3883,N,00434.4648,E,1,03,4.5,-5.1,M,47.1,M,,0000*73"

Or 51°57'23,1600"N;004°34'27,5760"E

In another GIS software with no GPS i get the following x and y values at the same location using the above projected system.
X: 99128,7851960541
Y: 441194,717554809

I allready tried different approach but stil no success. The Goal is to visualize the current GPS position at realtime in the GIS software.

Thx

Comment: do you have the formulas to convert?

Comment: Post your question to gis.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The best answer would be to use a third party library to do the conversion for you.  Such as [ArcGIS's GeometryService.Project web method](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/project.html) or [PROJ.4's API](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/ProjAPI).

If you want to do the math yourself, you'll have to look at the [spatial reference](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28992/) and do the math yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `PROJ.4` Api you can get the Proj4 Transformation definition string from
 this link: http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28992/proj4/

If you want to implement that transfomration for yourself:

Its an `Oblique Stereographic projection`, exact paramters to use: [epsg/28992](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/28992/html/)

The formulas are described in http://www.epsg.org/guides/docs/g7-2.pdf
on page 62ff, There is also an example for the Amersfoort RD.